# Can not install Gnome on Oracle Linux 6 vbox

Tags: centos, gnome, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox running on Windows 10 host and Oracle Linux 6 guest. I have been trying to get Gnome by running

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System" Desktop "General Purpose Desktop" \
"Graphical Administration Tools" "Legacy X Window System compatibility" \
system-config-lvm
```

as recommended [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2556908) but I get `No packages in any requested group available to install or update` message.

If I run

```
yum grouplist
```

I get `No such command: grouplist`

The reason I need Gnome is to be able to download files from a website where I have to log in first giving some credentials which I have no idea how to do. By using

```
curl /tmp/file_name 'http://www.websiteaddress.com/the/rest/of/the/url'
```

I managed to download one file but for some reason I can't download more.

I have tried to install firefox

```
sudo yum install firefox
```

but this didn't work either. In response I got `This system is not registered with ULN (. . .) No package firefox available`

I haven't used Oracle Linux before and I haven't found anything useful on the web so far so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about `yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop" `?

Comment: the response I get is `No such command: groups`

Comment: All right, and when you try `yum groupinstall basic-desktop desktop-platform x11 fonts`?

Comment: then I get `No packages in any requested group available to install or update`

Comment: Maybe you don't have working repositories? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30506060/7211502).

Comment: the first wget command given in that thread worked fine but the other `wget https://public-yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-ORACLE-el5` results in a message `certificate common name "yum.oracle.com" doesn't match requested host name "public-yum.oracle.com"` and there's suggestion to connect unsecurely

Comment: Why do you have `ORACLE` in link, when there should be `oracle` in lowercase?

Comment: a mistake in the comment, not done when the command was executed

Comment: Ok, try to remove `s` from `https` in second wget.

Comment: First of all you are using Oracle Linux. You can setup **free** oracle repositories from http://yum.oracle.com/.

Very next thing is that you might use even older box. It would be nice if you provide output of `/etc/*-release`

Comment: if I run `/etc/*-release` what I get is `/etc/oracle-release: line 1: Oracle: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to deal with `No such command: grouplist` by doing what is [here](https://flashdba.com/2012/10/08/this-system-is-not-registered-with-uln-rhn/) - that is:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://public-yum.oracle.com/public-yum-ol6.repo
```

It's pretty much what was posted as a resolution in [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506060/redhat-no-package-make-available) given in one of the comments above, except in the answer to that thread there was a typo so it didn't work.

Now I can run the command to install gui but it won't work because of other issues.